# Группировка новостей по пользователю

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails, group-by

Не получается написать запрос с группировкой как в новостной ленте социальных сетей.

К примеру, есть таблица всех новостей (котороя связана полиморфной связью с таблицами в которых подробное описание новости) столбцы: id, user_id, message_id, message_type;

```
id: 1, user_id: 1, message_id: 4, message_type: 'Warning'
id: 2, user_id: 1, message_id: 5, message_type: 'Warning'
id: 3, user_id: 1, message_id: 6, message_type: 'Warning'
id: 4, user_id: 2, message_id: 4, message_type: 'Error'
id: 5, user_id: 2, message_id: 1, message_type: 'Exception'
id: 6, user_id: 1, message_id: 2, message_type: 'Exception'
id: 7, user_id: 1, message_id: 3, message_type: 'Exception'
id: 8, user_id: 2, message_id: 4, message_type: 'Exception'
```

Не получается написать запрос, который выдаст последние новости сгруппированные по одинаковым **последовательно идущими** message_type для пользователя.

Например:

```
id: 8, user_id: 2, message_id: 4, message_type: 'Exception'
id: {6,7} user_id: 1, message_id: {2,3}, message_type: 'Exception'
id: 5, user_id: 2, message_id: 1, message_type: 'Exception'
id: 4, user_id: 2, message_id: 4, message_type: 'Error'
id: {1, 2, 3}, user_id: 1, message_id: {4, 5}, message_type: 'Warning'
```

Не хочется использовать вложенные запросы, т.к. таблица большая. Будет извлекаться по 20 новостей. База данных PostgreSQL. 
Как можно это сделать?

P.S. Задавал вопрос на английском ресурсе, но либо я его не корректно задал, либо меня не поняли. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30227391/postgree-double-group-by-repeating-attribute

Comment: что-то вроде select user_id, message_type, array_agg(id), array_agg(message_id) from t group by user_id, message_type;

Comment: Такая группировка не подходит, нужно в новость по одному user сгруппировать последовательные одинаковые  действия.
Пример стандартной группировки http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/399c3/2
Сливаются строки с id 5 и 8

Comment: не совсем понял. проблема в том, что они именно не последовательные (т.е. их идентификатор отличается больше чем на 1)?

Comment: Проблема в том, что между ними два 'Exception' user_id: 1, значит они не должны группироваться.

Comment: а в постановке задачи что-то про это сказано? вижу, что на англоязычной версии ответили так же как я, это какбэ намекает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я нашел только 1 способ:

1. С помощью оконной ф-ии lead() определить, кода была изменена пара (пользователь, тип сообщения)
2. С помощью оконной ф-ии sum() задать порядковый номер для каждой новой пары
3. Сгруппировать по номеру пары и получить желаемую информацию

Проверка:

```
create table test (
  id serial primary key,
  user_id integer,
  message_id integer,
  message_type varchar
);

insert into test (user_id, message_id, message_type) 
values 
(1, 4, 'Warning'),
(1, 5, 'Warning'),
(1, 6, 'Warning'),
(2, 4, 'Error'),
(2, 1, 'Exception'),
(1, 2, 'Exception'),
(1, 3, 'Exception'),
(2, 4, 'Exception')
;

select 
    array_agg(grouped.id) as record_ids,
    grouped.user_id,
    array_agg(grouped.message_id) as message_ids,
    grouped.message_type
from (
    select changed.*, 
        sum(changed.changed) over (order by changed.id desc) as group_n
    from (
        select tt.*,
            case when lag((user_id, message_type)) over (order by tt.id desc) is distinct from (user_id, message_type) then 1 else 0 end as changed
        from test tt
    ) changed
    order by id desc
) grouped
group by grouped.group_n, grouped.user_id, grouped.message_type
order by grouped.group_n
;
```

Результат:

```
record_ids | user_id | message_ids | message_type 
------------+---------+-------------+--------------
 {8}        |       2 | {4}         | Exception
 {7,6}      |       1 | {3,2}       | Exception
 {5}        |       2 | {1}         | Exception
 {4}        |       2 | {4}         | Error
 {3,2,1}    |       1 | {6,5,4}     | Warning
(5 rows)
```